# $request->json()->all() return empty Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, request

Why my request becomes empty when i use $request->json()->all(), below my code:

```php
$request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();
$request->setMethod('POST');
$request->query->add(['foo' => 'bar']);
$postData = $request->json()->all();

dd($postData);
```

The result is:

```
[]
```

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

To add parameters to a request object use `add()` like this:

```php
$request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();
$request->setMethod('POST');

// single items 'test' and '123'
$request->request->add(['test', '123']);

// $key => value
$request->request->add(['test' => '123']); 
 
$postData = $request->all();

dd($postData);
```

The output is then something like this:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "test"
  1 => "123"
  "test" => "123"
]
```

`$request->json()` gets the content of the request ([Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_json)) as json - which is `NULL` in your case.

You can run `dd($request)` and see:

```
Illuminate\Http\Request {#1796 ▼
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: []
  #userResolver: null
  #routeResolver: null
  +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#1798 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "test" => "123"
    ]
  }
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#1795 ▼
    #parameters: array:3 [▼
      0 => "test"
      1 => "123"
      "test" => "123"
    ]
  }
  +query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#1797 ▶}
  +server: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag {#1779 ▶}
  +files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#1791 ▶}
  +cookies: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#1794 ▶}
  +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag {#1778 ▶}
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: null
  #requestUri: null
  #baseUrl: null
  #basePath: null
  #method: null
  #format: null
  #session: null
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -preferredFormat: null
  -isHostValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  -isSafeContentPreferred: null
  pathInfo: "/"
  requestUri: ""
  baseUrl: ""
  basePath: ""
  method: "POST"
  format: "html"
}
```